# Reporting statements: He {would/will} probably be back soon

Tags: modal-verbs, reported-speech

I'm wondering if there's any reason why *will* would be uncorrect in the following phrase:

> She said that he *will* probably be back soon.

reporting the statement:

> He's likely to be back soon.

The book I'm reading suggests to use would, should or ought to.

---

Also for the following:

> I refuse to accept that he is dishonest.

To report it I would have used either can't or couldn't (maybe she still can't believe it?)

> She said that she *can't/couldn't* believe that he is dishonest.

**I realize that the book may not write all the possible words, but am I wrong somehow?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> She said that he **will probably** be back soon.

I think *will probably* is closer to the intended meaning of *likely*. *Should* or *ought to* are more middle of the road and imply some outside influence. (He **should** be back soon, but...)

> I **refuse** to accept that he is dishonest.

[***refuse***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/refuse) by definition has more to do with personal belief or motive (decline, reject), rather than *can't* or *couldn't*, which could negate for other reasons. I would keep *ability* in mind when using *can*.

Comment: Do you think in the latter "would" would be more appropriate ?